# Restrict the 'slideToggle' animation at once when click the radiobutton?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to restrict the action of slideToggle animation at once  when someone click the radiobutton..? I have a yes or no question and I wrote a simple JQuery for showing a hidden div when I click 'yes' radiobutton, the problem is its repeating the hide/show action when I click the 'yes' button..

any solutions for this...?

Although I'm new in JQuery though my JQuery code is given below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#d01').click(function(){
            $(".c01").slideToggle();    
    });

    $('#d02').click(function(){
             $(".c01").hide();
    });
)};
```

(#d01) - stands for 'yes' radio button.

(#d02) - stands for 'no' radio button.

(.c01) - stands for hidden div.

Akhil

Comment: @3nigma I like the sliding animation, so that is why I just used it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `slideToggle` to `slideDown`. [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) will hide the element if it's already shown, and show it if it's hidden. That is to say, it "toggles" between hidden and shown, hence the name.

[`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) on the other hand will display the matched elements if they are hidden, and do nothing otherwise.

Note that you could also use [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), and you could also use [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) in place of `hide` in your `#d02` click event handler if you want the animation to take effect there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#d01').click(function(){
            $(".c01").slideDown();    
    });

    $('#d02').click(function(){
             $(".c01").slideUp();
    });
)};
```